# Python regex match list but not list with dictionaries

Tags: python

I have text file that looks like

```
logSet1 = [
                       { log1 = event1,
                         log2 = event2
}
]


logSet2 = [
                         log1,
                         log2
]
```

I want to write a regex that match only logSet2 not logSet1. I have tried

```
\= \[[ ]*\n([^\{].*\n)*?[ ]*\]\
```

but it matches to both.. I thought `[^\{]` would force it to match with the string that does not begin with `\{`.

Comment: I would parse this ugly txt file manually; line by line. If you're keen on regex, maybe split this up into multiple regular expressions.

Comment: Do you want to support nested lists?

Comment: Where does that file come from? Is there no parser for it already? That would be rather odd.

Comment: @woockashek I don't need to support nested lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is programmatically structured consider loading it into data structures and navigating those.

For your regex itself there are some features of the language you may want to be more comfortable with.

```
"[ ]*" -- any number of spaces is not great for what you're angling for. Tabs and non breaking white spaces will through you for a loop, as will system differences (\n vs \r vs \r\n). Try just \s*
```

\w is also your friend (word characters,  a-zA-Z0-9 and some punctuation)

In that vein I'd propose:

```
\w[\w\s]*= \[\s*[\w,\s]*\]
```

A word character, followed by as many word or spaces, followed by an =, a space and the open brace. "\w[\w\s]*= [" gets you "logSet2 = [". Then as many whitespace characters, followed by word characters, commas and spaces and finally terminated by a bracket. logSet1 with the curly brace and = will never match.

The drawback is that is the data, here represented as "log1" and "log2" have these characters the whole regex approach falls apart.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just a follow up on this, my actual content is significantly more complex than this. Each element could have a bunch of mess in them (not only `\w,\s`). Is it possible to match based on whether the line does not begin with `\{`?

Comment: Then I would recommend writer a log parser that "listens" at "=" + open bracket, maintains a open/close brace stack, and stops when the open bracket closes.  At that point parse the whole thing into a data structure instead of using regex.